# Chaining/grouping resources in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have a variety of places in my Chef recipes where operations need to be run in sequence, and that sequence needs to be referenced in several places. E.g., one sequence of operations is "stop Tomcat, recompile the app, start Tomcat", which can be triggered by, among other events, "the application source tree changes".

I need to be able to trigger these sequences of operations need with both `notifies` attributes from various resources (including the `:delayed` functionality), plus `subscribes` attributes on the sequences themselves, since the sequences could be triggered by resources in other recipes that will restart Tomcat if it's around, but don't actually depend on the Tomcat recipe.

What is the optimal way to manage these groups of operations?

I see from [the Chef docs](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html) that a way to handle this is to have any relevant event notify all of these operations in sequence:

```
git 'repo' do
  notifies :stop, 'service[tomcat]', :delayed
  notifies :run, 'recompile_app', :delayed
  notifies :start, 'service[tomcat]', :delayed
end
```

However, there are rather a lot of resources this sequence of events could be triggered by, and this level of code duplication seems inefficient and error-prone.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: If you have many places where some kind of code repeats, you should extract it into library (http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html) or LWRP (http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_custom.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an [LWRP](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp.html) or a [definition](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html). LWRPs will create a wrapper around the collection of resources, so it will only appear once in the resource collection. It's like an extension of Chef. Definitions will wrap a series of resources, but each resource still exists in the resource collection.

In your example, I would use a definition:

```
define :my_thing do
  git 'repo' do
    # ...
  end

  service 'tomcat' do
    action :stop
  end

  execute 'recompile_app' do
    action :run
  end

  service 'tomcat' do
    action :start
  end
end
```

Sources:

- [Chef Definitions](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html)
- [Chef LWRPs](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp.html)

Comment: What is the appropriate way to replace the use of "subscribes" for these definitions? Simply adding a `subscribes` clause didn't work for me. I have some resources that will need to invoke the definition if its cookbook is included, or not if it isn't.

Comment: The login is flipped.

Comment: Which login do you mean? Also, how would I invoke this definition in a delayed fashion, like the resources in my post have?

Comment: I meant to say "logic*"